# Why are all of the values in my array null?

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone tell me why in the second array I am getting null instead of the information from the file?

Here is my code in the main method:

```
    ...OTHER CODE

    String[] fileDataNames = new String[10];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        fileDataAll[j][0] = fileDataNames[j];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(fileDataNames));
```

Comment: If this were my problem, I'd run my code through my favorite IDE's debugger, inspecting the value of the key variables as I stepped through the code. Why not give this a try and see what you can find out?

Comment: The value of `fileDataNames[j];` is empty, you have not uses this array yet.

Comment: Well there you go! Sharp eyes @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change below from :

```
fileDataAll[j][0] = fileDataNames[j];
```

to

```
fileDataNames[j] = fileDataAll[j][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You invert the operation, it's the value from `fileDataAll` that needs to go to `fileDataName`

```
for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_VOLUNTEERS; j++) {
    fileDataNames[j] = fileDataAll[j][0];
}
```